# How to I access many layers into a json array? Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

After fighting with this for a couple of hours, I think I need to rephrase the question.

I have an object that contains and array of objects;

```
                                Playlist: [
```

{
    "added_at": "2015-11-13T20:55:06Z",
    "added_by": {
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify_canada"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify_canada",
      "id": "spotify_canada",
      "type": "user",
      "uri": "spotify:user:spotify_canada"
    },
    "is_local": false,
    "track": {
      "album": {
        "album_type": "album",
        "available_markets": [
          "CA",
          "MX",
          "US"
        ],
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/6Fr2rQkZ383FcMqFyT7yPr"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6Fr2rQkZ383FcMqFyT7yPr",
        "id": "6Fr2rQkZ383FcMqFyT7yPr",
        "images": [
          {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8b47495ce0c4a341f7196f70bcf4361e6257c1a0",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/da1e8958b6260e832660d0c5f3c80e9569c388c8",
            "width": 300
          },
          {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/478dbfd0e579dee7392707b9a6848faff0cdfefd",
            "width": 64
          }
        ],
        "name": "Purpose (Deluxe)",
        "type": "album",
        "uri": "spotify:album:6Fr2rQkZ383FcMqFyT7yPr"
      },
      "artists": [
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1uNFoZAHBGtllmzznpCI3s"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1uNFoZAHBGtllmzznpCI3s",
          "id": "1uNFoZAHBGtllmzznpCI3s",
          "name": "Justin Bieber",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:1uNFoZAHBGtllmzznpCI3s"
        }
      ],
      "available_markets": [
        "CA",
        "MX",
        "US"
      ],
      "disc_number": 1,
      "duration_ms": 205680,
      "explicit": false,
      "external_ids": {
        "isrc": "USUM71511919"
      },
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/4B0JvthVoAAuygILe3n4Bs"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4B0JvthVoAAuygILe3n4Bs",
      "id": "4B0JvthVoAAuygILe3n4Bs",
      "name": "What Do You Mean?",
      "popularity": 93,
      "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/13da79dc4803f65092d583f6e3bdf1fc4d8344e5",
      "track_number": 3,
      "type": "track",
      "uri": "spotify:track:4B0JvthVoAAuygILe3n4Bs"
    }
  },

In side of each of these objects is another object I am trying to assign to scope.

So this - playlist {items [ {track {name: songname} } ] }

How do I go about assigning the track.name to scope?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code and expected results

Comment: Please see edit above.  Thanks charlietfl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you just have a typo but why are you assigning your blank array to data.items instead of the other way around?

```
$scope.playListInfo = [];
$scope.getPlayList = function() {
  Spotify.getPlaylistTracks('spotify_canada', '7ndCD5pklOTcrTcv4DErmI')
    .then(function(data) {
        var i = 0;
        for(i; i < data.items.length; i++) {
           var dataToKeep = {};
           dataToKeep.name = data.items[i].track.name;
           dataToKeep.artist = data.items[i].track.artist;
           $scope.playListInfo[i] = dataToKeep;
        }
      });
   };
```

Comment: Arg!  Yes, that makes much more sense.  Now that seems to be iterating but playListTrack looks like an array of null.

Playlist: [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null
]

When I output to the page.

Comment: AH, must have been an edit in the pipe there.  You suggestion worked.  Thanks a load!

Comment: So while I have you engaged, what would be the best way to do the same iteration but assign more than one attribute to the new array?  So for example to create an array of records with track.name and track.id.  I'm a bit of an array noob!

Comment: I would recommend making an array of objects and in the for loop assign the values you need just like you did above. So $scope.spotifyStuff = [] replaces playListTrack. 
Then in the for loop var dataToKeep = {}.
dataToKeep.name = track.name;
dataToKeep.artist = track.artist;
etc.etc;
$scope.playListTrack[i] = dataToKeep;

Comment: I updated my response to show using more than one value from the response.

Comment: Cool. Will give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I don't have sufficient points to comment. So, I am creating this post.

The JSON data has `items` and not `item`. Also, I think you'd have to create a  $scope.playlistTrack array outside the function.

```
$scope.playlistTrack = []; 
$scope.getPlayList = function () {
    Spotify.getPlaylistTracks('spotify_canada', '7ndCD5pklOTcrTcv4DErmI')
        .then(function (datas) {
            angular.forEach(datas, function(data){
                data.items = $scope.playlistTrack;
            });
        });
};
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: This give me TypeError: Cannot set property 'items' of null.